# Laravel OCI8 not installing

Tags: php, oracle, laravel-5, oracle-call-interface, oci8

Summary of problem

I have oci8 installed for php 7.1.19

Running on Laravel Framework 5.6.3

//error i get when trying to install Yajra oci8 github for laravel

Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

Problem 1

- yajra/laravel-oci8 v5.6.0 requires ext-oci8 >=2.0.0 -> the requested PHP extension oci8 is missing from your system.
- yajra/laravel-oci8 5.6.x-dev requires ext-oci8 >=2.0.0 -> the requested PHP extension oci8 is missing from your system.
- yajra/laravel-oci8 5.6.x-dev requires ext-oci8 >=2.0.0 -> the requested PHP extension oci8 is missing from your system.
- Installation request for yajra/laravel-oci8 5.6.* -> satisfiable by yajra/laravel-oci8[5.6.x-dev, v5.6.0].

To enable extensions, verify that they are enabled in your .ini files:

- C:\wamp\bin\php\php7.1.9\php.ini

You can also run php --ini inside terminal to see which files are used by PHP in CLI mode.

Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.

//

When i make a test.php in WAMP it works and no errors, but now i want it to work for laravel as well.

Code snippet

```
$conn = oci_connect('Name', 'Password', 'Localhost');

if ($conn) {
    echo "connect succesfull";
}
```

\\

The command i run to install it in laravel is:

'composer require yajra/laravel-oci8:"5.6.*"'

I understand that this might not be the right command, soo i tried this:

'composer require yajra/laravel-oci8:"7.1.19"'

But that one doesnt exists

I am kinda stuck now. Anyone can help me?

Comment: https://github.com/yajra/laravel-oci8/issues/411

Comment: Which OS you are using?

Comment: Windows 7 x86 @SachinVairagi

Comment: Please share the steps you followed or you can also check - http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/technote-php-instant-084410.html

Comment: @SachinVairagi It is already working in a php file, the only problem is that it doesn't work for installing the laravel github

Comment: Please check - https://github.com/yajra/laravel-oci8/issues/353

Comment: Already did, isnt helping. @SachinVairagi

Comment: Hey Nanko, did you get sorted? What was the issue please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# How to install OCI8 in windows 

## Instantclient Version 12.2.0.1.0

##### Xampp
##### php 7.2.4
##### Windows 10

### Step 1
```

Download OCI8 2.1.8 - 7.2 Thread Safe (TS) x86

```
### Step 2
```

Extract the file to xampp\ext

```
### Step 3
```

Add code to file xampp\php.ini

`extension=php_oci8.dll`

```
### Step 4
```

Download the "Instant Client Package - Basic" for Windows from the OTN Instant Client page. 
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/winsoft-085727.html

Because PHP is 32 bit, use the 32 bit version of Instant Client.
(http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/technote-php-instant-084410.html)

`Instant Client Package - Basic Version 12.2.0.1.0`

```
### Step 5
```

Extract the Instant Client folder to C:\instantclient_12_2

```
### Step 6
```

Edit the Windows PATH environment setting and add this path

```
C:\instantclient_12_2


### Step 7
```

Restart

Comment: Also see https://blogs.oracle.com/opal/installing-xampp-for-php-and-oracle-database from the maintainer of the OCI8 extension.